# Image height for div

Tags: css

Can't seem to get the height of my image to fit 100% within my div (blank div) .The image is for the homepage slider as shown here, http://www.acepools.ca   As you can see, the height of the image is cut off.

Any suggestions?

```
#background{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index: -1;
}

#background > *{
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the CSS3 `background-size` property.

[Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: Interesting but now I got a vertical scroll bar.I need it to fit in the window before the bottom header.